# if statement within mysqli::prepare

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Is it posible to insert an if statement within a mysqli::prepare statement?

```
$check->$DBH->prepare('IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users WHERE username=?)>0');
$check->bind_param('i',$username);
$check->execute();
```

If so, my next question is how to handle the query? Would it return 1 if found, or an affected row or a result.

```
$result=$check->affected_rows;//rows affected
```

Or

```
$check->bind_result($rowExists);//row exist
```

Or

```
$check->num_rows();//number of rows
```

Or is all he above possible?

Comment: No.  `if` as a statement in MySQL can only be used in stored programs such as procedures, functions, and triggers.

Comment: This is exact case of "XY problem". For some reason you are trying to overengineer something usual and silly, like checking user existence in database

Comment: what you are trying to do? to check user existence? just run a **regular** select query without whatever conditional statements

Comment: @YourCommonSense essentially yes. I know it can be done using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=?` but just wanted to see if using If statements were possible as it require less reads? according to Andrew Kelly: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx
Wasn't aware of illegal SQL in prepared statements.

Comment: Why does this problem bother you at all? do you experience any particular problem with checking user at the moment? Why do you thing that article is applicable at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Just thought it might've been a better way of proceeding the outcome of `true:false;`. Obviously not :p

Comment: in fact, for a users table you don't need count(*) either. for the apparently unique username `SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username=?` is enough

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok that's a better idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statement is dealing with **data only**

**It doesn't affect your SQL statement in any way.**

**Any working** SQL statement with dynamical data literals substituted with placeholders would work

If you are passing illegal SQL into prepared statement, it won't work.